# Firebase Firestore update query doesn't execute because of the promise chaining. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This code is being executed in a firebase cloud function to make a stripe charge after being triggered by a document being added to firestore. This is just a snippet where the problem lies. The code is supposed to charge a card, and upon success, update the 'dexCoinBal' value in firestore with a newBalance. I approached this by getting the previous value and then moving along with the update. However, the update doesn't seem to run at all. It's probably something to do with chaining the promises but I can't figure out what it is exactly. If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong that'd be great. I clearly don't understand promises well enough.

```
 function charge (tok, amt, curr, uid) {
        const token = tok;
        const amount = amt;
        const currency = curr;
        const fStor = admin.firestore();

        stripe.charges.create({
            amount,
            currency,
            description: 'Example charge',
            source: token
        }).then(function(result){
            return fStor.collection('users').get();
        }).then(function(doc){
            if(doc.exists){
                const prev = doc.data().dexCoinBal;
                var numDexCoins = amt / (0.25 * 100);
                var newBal = numDexCoins + prev;

                //Update the number of dexcoins in database
                fStor.collection('users').doc(uid).update({
                    dexCoinBal: newBal
                });
            }
        });   
    }
```

Full code below. Fixed the issue.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const fStor = admin.firestore();
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
fStor.settings = settings;

// TODO: Remember to set token using >> firebase functions:config:set stripe.token="SECRET_STRIPE_TOKEN_HERE"
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);

function charge (tok, amt, curr, uid) {
    const token = tok;
    const amount = amt;
    const currency = curr;

    console.log("Outside");
    return stripe.charges.create({
        amount,
        currency,
        description: 'Example charge',
        source: token
    }).then(function(result){
        console.log("First Then");
        return fStor.collection('users').doc(uid).get();
    }).then(function(doc){
        console.log("Second Then");
        if(doc.exists){
            const prev = doc.data().dexCoinBal;
            var numDexCoins = amt / (0.25 * 100);
            var newBal = numDexCoins + prev;

            //Update the number of dexcoins in database
            fStor.collection('users').doc(uid).update({
                dexCoinBal: newBal
            });
        }
    });   
}

exports.createCharge = functions.firestore
    .document('charges/{chargeId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      // Get an object representing the document
      // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
      const data = snap.data();

      // access a particular field as you would any JS property
      const token = data.token;
      const amount = data.amount;
      const currency = data.currency;
      const uid = data.uid;

    // perform desired operations ...
      return charge(token, amount, currency, uid);
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to figure out which line is the final one that appears to be being executed? That'll give you a big hint as to where the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

1/ By doing `return fStor.collection('users').get();` you are returning a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) **and not a `DocumentSnapshot`**. See the doc of the `get()` method [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get).

The doc says that "A `QuerySnapshot` contains zero or more `DocumentSnapshot` objects representing the results of a query. The documents can be accessed as an array via the `docs` property or enumerated using the `forEach` method. "

Therefore when, in then next then(), you do `doc.data()` you most probably get an error.

2/ The second problem, IMHO, is that you don't return anything in your charge function. Since, in a Cloud Function, you shall return a promise (or a value in specific cases) you should probably return a promise from your function. You should probably do as follows, but it is difficult to be 100% sure as you didn't publish the entire code of your Cloud Function.

```
return stripe.charges.create({
       ....
    }).then(function(result){
        ....
    }).then(function(collection){
        ....
    });
```

If you add the entire code we may be able to help you more precisely.

---

I would also suggest that you look at these two *must see* videos from the Firebase team, about Cloud Functions and promises: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk.

Comment: I had spotted problem number 1 earlier today and changed it to fStor.collection('users').doc(uid).get(). I'll update the question with my full code after I test it a bit. Also, thanks for the resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were absolutely right! I needed to return a promise from the charge function.

Comment: Happy that I could help you! ;-)

Comment: Just one extra comment, now that I see your full code (after your update): do not forget to add a `catch()` in your promise chaining. See the two videos for more details.